# Dynamics 365 API deactivate processes

Tags: dynamics-crm, etl, microsoft-dynamics, dynamic-sql

I would like to automatically deactivate and activate processes on Dynamics CRM so I can upload data in between. Processes include updating information and setting one field to be another when it is inputted by user.

Is it possible to do this through the API? The documentation I saw online was mainly about querying from CRM

Reading documentation, looking on forums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use PATCH operation

workflows table holds your Dynamics 365 workflows and actions and you need to find GUID of your particualr process

```
https://abc.crm.dynamics.com//api/data/v9.2/workflows(c92dca98-8a13-44b9-bd13-02da90c8a38d)
```

body as below

```
{
    "statecode": 1,//state
    "statuscode": 2 // status
}
```

just tested this on Postman.

below jquery code snippet

```
var record = {};
record.statecode = 1; // State
record.statuscode = 2; // Status

$.ajax({
    type: "PATCH",
    url: Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.2/workflows(c92dca98-8a13-44b9-bd13-02da90c8a38d)",
    async: true,
    headers: {
        "OData-MaxVersion": "4.0",
        "OData-Version": "4.0",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Prefer": "odata.include-annotations=*"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(record),
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log("Record updated");
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```